# Google API request recieving bad results

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, discord

I am creating an application that will be able to translate japanese to english. The problem is that when you run the app, it usually returns a bunch of non-sense. For example, translating こんにちは turns into 'S" ao ao', when it should translate to 'Hello'.

```
   let link = `https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=ja&tl=en&dt=t&q=${words.join(" ")}`
console.log(link);

request.get(link, function(error, response, body) {
    message.channel.send(body[0][0][0]);
```

I believe it could be a problem with non-english characters, but I am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mess up on my part, the URL was not correct for encoding of non-english characters, the correct format is:

```
https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=ja&tl=en&dt=t&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=`+encodeURIComponent(words)
```